# [NSConcreteValue floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, unrecognized-selector

In my project I have this problem.

I have a NSDictionary, when I try to call a value sometimes the app crash and Xcode give me this error:

- [NSConcreteValue floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here is the code to call the value of the dictionary (The value isn't nil):

```
    float valueTest = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] floatValue];
```

**EDIT**

This is the structure of my NSDictionary:

```
 {
    kind = 1;
    new = "0.02696711";
    old = "0.04064206";
}
```

The dictionary is never equal to nil

The method is this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
}
```

The dictionary is created by the system. I check with logs the content of the dictionary and it's already correct and already the same format.

I don't have other information.

I'm searching for a method to prevent the crash.

Sorry for possible english errors

Thanks

Comment: “The value isn't nil” No, but it isn’t an NSNumber either. That’s the problem.

Comment: @matt ok but why sometimes it works and sometimes no ? How I have to change my code? thanks

Comment: @matt I edited my question. I repeat that the values on my NSDictionary are never equal to nil, and the value in  key "new" is always the same as a float

Comment: Look at `NSValue`.

Comment: @matt I reedit the question

Comment: @Sulthan what do you suggest to do?

Comment: @BlackRock What property are you observing?

Comment: I add an observer in this mode:  [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"videoDeviceInput.device.ISO" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:ISOContext];. I checked the values through the logs, and even before the crash the value is always correct @matt. And the class of the value is always __NSCFNumber

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: @matt maybe the answer that you deleted solve the problem. I'm doing some test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it appears we are trying to observe the ISO property of an AVCaptureDevice. And it appears that sometimes it arrives as an NSValue that is not typed as an NSNumber. I don't know why that is, but you can check with this condition:

```
strcmp(@encode(float), [[change valueForKey:@"new"] objCType]) == 0
```

If that passes, you can just extract the value directly:

```
float f;
[[change valueForKey:@"new"] getValue:&f];
```

Comment: I did some tests and the problem seems to be solved. Thank you Matt

Comment: Glad that worked. As I say, I do not know why the float value is being wrapped as an NSConcreteValue. It may be a KVO bug.